# Capture max used bandwidth

Tags: performance-monitoring

I have a Windows Server 2003 that I'd like to measure the max used bandwidth.
I'd like to have a report showing the peak bandwidth on an hourly and
daily basis.
Can I do this using Performance monitor somehow?

Comment: I'll leave a comment as I am posting on a cell phone and don't have links at hand, but I believe MRTG and it's successor does this. It has a peaks graph entry. It's a visual graph more than a number don't know if that fits the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance Monitor can capture to various file formats (with the advantage that this can be done without an interactive session needed).

This can include CSV which can be loaded into (say) Excel and then processed.

To set this up:

- From Start | Run enter PerfMon
- Select Performance Logs and Alerts | Counter Logs
- Action | New Log Settings
- Enter a name
- Select the performance objects (groups of counters) or counters you want
- Enter you sample rate, to capture maxima you'll need a reasonably short interval
- On the log files tab select the format and location. The tools can auto number files to avoid overwriting.
- On the schedule tab select when you want data to be collected.

When you have the CSV files, use Excel and its normal functions to extract peaks.